# Jquery make div always scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a div that contains a table. This table is dynamically updated, and is filling up with data as user is using our website.
Is it possible to force this div to always be scrolled to bottom? So that the user will always be able to see the bottom most table row that was added.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes there is, but from a UX stand point, if you want the user to see the latest row first. Why would you not sort the table the oposite way?

Comment: I would add another point to that of @laymanje.  If you are dynamically updating via ajax you could insert the new rows at the top of the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be something like

```
...onRowAdded = function() {
    $('#myTable').animate({scrollTop: $('#myTable').attr('scrollHeight')});
};
```

Note, if the rows are added very often, you would want to use setTimeout with blocking variable check at the beginning to prevent scrolling down more often than twice per second or so. This technique is discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on)

UPDATE

Starting with jQuery 1.6 it is better to use .prop() instead of .attr() (see comments to this question):

```
onRowAdded = function() {
    $('#myTable').animate({scrollTop: $('#myTable').prop('scrollHeight')});
};
```

Comment: You may have to use .prop instead of .attr

Comment: @cmcculloh, you are right - starting with jQuery 1.6 it is more appropriate to use .prop('scrollHeight') as it is not an attribute, i.e. does not have a place in HTML element's attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Set the update element as position absolute and bottom:0

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Mdzmx/

Answer (score 2):

Try something like it :

Create a anchor like `<a id='bottomDiv'></a>` and insert a javascript like this `document.getElementById('bottomOfDiv').scrollIntoView(true);`

I made a example here
http://jsfiddle.net/PTmpL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

but use the `bottom` css property to have the bottom most element, visible on the page

`element{
   bottom:0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [ScrollTo JQuery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). Just use

```
element.scrollTo('max', {axis: 'y'});
```

or

```
element.scrollTo('max', duration, {axis: 'y'});
```

This plugin has the added benifit of having a nice smooth scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the easy solution !!!

```
element.scrollTo(element.get(0).scrollHeight);
```