# Leave menu bar fixed on top when scrolled

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen some websites that when the user scrolls down the page a box would pop-up to the right or left...

Also, noticed this template: http://www.mvpthemes.com/maxmag/ the designer does a nice job leaving the nav bar fixed on top.

Now, how are these done? I guess it uses jquery to get the position of the page and to show the box.

Can you please guide me to where I can find a snippet so I can learn to do something like that.

Comment: Try this one. http://www.backslash.gr/demos/jquery-sticky-navigation/

Comment: I've closed this as "needs more focus (too broad)", because you're asking about two different effects A) having a navigation bar which is kept at the top of the page, and B) opening popup box on the left or right of the page when the user scrolls down. While these are, potentially, related, they are significantly different effects, which have different implementations. You also are asking for "where I can find a snippet" which is an off-topic resource request. However, that could be edited out, if all the answers are compatible with doing so.

Answer (score 162):

This effect is typically achieved by having some jquery logic as follows:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

This says once the window has scrolled past a certain number of vertical pixels, it adds a class to the menu that changes it's position value to "fixed".

For complete implementation details see: http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/F4BmP/

Comment: Couldn't you shorten this by doing something like: `$('.menu').toggleClass('fixed', $(window).scrollTop() > 50);`?

Comment: @MichaelCalkins Yeah (another one is: `$('.menu')[($(window).scrollTop() > num ? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class']('fixed');`) but I think the way it's written allows for maximum readability.

Comment: For IE, you may need to add `z-index:1;` under `.fixed` to ensure the menu is over the top.

Comment: Unfortunately this implementation will fire whatever function/interaction you place in the if statement 6 times every time the user scrolls one click and 9 times every time they click the scroll bar arrow down or up. Possible solution to the multiple events here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on

Comment: Thank for the solution. It was unbelievable how many different ways I had to search to get to this topic >:(

Comment: toggleClass() shortens the code but it gives a weird flickering while switching between class.

Comment: @adamb, I have on the issue in this, if the user already scrolls and then refresh the page then div is not displaying. I am scrolling then displaying the div.

Answer (score 21):

In this example, you may show your menu centered.

### HTML

```
<div id="main-menu-container">
    <div id="main-menu">
        //your menu
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.f-nav{  /* To fix main menu container */
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#main-menu-container {
    text-align: center; /* Assuming your main layout is centered */
}
#main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1024px; /* Your menu's width */
}
```

### JS

```
$("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $('#main-menu-container');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 125) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use css rules:

`position: fixed ;` and `top: 0px ;`

on your menu tag.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Let CSS do what it is designed to do. Adding functionality in JQuery adds unnecessary bulk to your project.

Comment: @PseudoNinja Yes but if you look at the page Wilson provided as an example, the menu bar is only "fixed" when the user has scrolled past  it's relative positioning. This cannot be achieved in CSS alone.

Answer (score 15):

same as adamb but I would add a dynamic variable num

```
num = $('.menuFlotante').offset().top;
```

to get the exact offset or position inside the window to avoid finding the right position.

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
             $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
         }
         else {
             num = $('.menuFlotante').offset().top;
             $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
         }
    });
```

Comment: This is great as it avoid  a common bug it happens with other examples. Chrome tends to sometimes add a stupid and nonsense gap between <body> and first <div>, usually with the height of that <div>. Thanks.

Comment: +1 this is a better solution! because of the use of variable value for comparison of .scrollTop(), and is helpful if you have sites being browsed in different devices like iPad etc which differ in the way the desktop browsers would behave.

Comment: @BornKillaz, it can be sorted by applying the css rule `*:empty {display:none;}`

Answer (score 7):

Or do this in more dynamic way

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var menu = $('.menu');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > menu.offset().top) {
        menu.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        menu.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

In CSS add class

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Needs to be `>=` instead of `>` or else the menu will jump in and out between being fixed as you scroll.

Answer (score 4):

try with sticky jquery plugin

https://github.com/garand/sticky

```js
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0});
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

check the link below, it has the html, css, JS and a live demo :) enjoy

http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD

```js
// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');

    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement+'px').show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

```css
* {font-family:arial; margin:0; padding:0;}
.logo {font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;color:#00a; font-style:italic;}
.intro {color:#777; font-style:italic; margin:10px 0;}
.menu {background:#00a; color:#fff; height:40px; line-height:40px;letter-spacing:1px; width:100%;}
.content {margin-top:10px;}
.menu-padding {padding-top:40px;}
.content {padding:10px;}
.content p {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="intro">Some tagline goes here</div>
```

Comment: That looks WAY more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

you may want to add:

```
 $(window).trigger('scroll')
```

to trigger the scroll event when you reload an already scrolled page. Otherwise you might get your menu out of position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            var pixels = 600; //number of pixels before modifying styles
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > pixels) {
                $('header').addClass('fixed');
            } else {
                $('header').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: When reloading, the browser auto scrolls to its last position, triggering the scroll event, otherwise if it doesn't auto scroll, you won't need to change menu's position.

Answer (score 2):

This is jquery code which is used to fixed the div when it touch a top of browser hope it will help a lot.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };

    var $el = $('#sidebar>div');
    var $window = $(window);
    var top = $el.parent().position().top;

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
        var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 172 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

        if (scrollTop < top + 10) {
            $el.css({
                top: (top - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        } else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
            $el.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $el.css({
                top: 0,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    }).scroll();
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

        var ControlDivTop = $('#cs_controlDivFix');

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
               ControlDivTop.stop().animate({ 'top': ($(this).scrollTop() - 62) + "px" }, 600);
            } else {
              ControlDivTop.stop().animate({ 'top': ($(this).scrollTop()) + "px" },600);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with your nav `div`:

```
div.fixed{
    postion: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you could trigger this effect using Intersection Observer API when certain elements enter or leave the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API