# How to build floating menu bar when scroll down

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, css-transitions

When I scrolled down site display black menu bar at the top look like float bar.
but I think there's jquery involved with this. I have tried CSS but seems not working for me like the way i want it to

```
#menucontainer {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height: 250px
}

#firstElement {
    margin-top: 250px
}
```

Here is the website basic idea of what I would like the menu to be like:

http://avathemes.com/WP/Hexic/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Leave menu bar fixed on top when scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled)

Answer (score 46):

Wrap your menu in an div or section with an ID or class.

```
#yourID.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
}

//STICKY NAV
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('#yourID').offset().top - parseFloat($('#yourID').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 100));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#yourID').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#yourID').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Can't remember where I got this from, so no salutations to me, but it worked for me.

Comment: Cool mate, thanks for shring... i think adding a transition effect to the width change would make it super cool.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, it provided a clean and quick solution to the authors problem, without need of any plugins or additional dependencies.

Comment: The code above might came from here: http://www.benmarshall.me/jquery-sticky-navigation/. As a bonus: jsFiddle demo provided.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

### CSS

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;}


body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    background:#bfbfbf;


}


h1, h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

h1.title {
    font-size: 46px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #6a6a6a;


}


h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.menuBtn {

    background: center center no-repeat transparent;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;

}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.wrap {
        /*background:url(../images/bg.png) top left repeat-x;*/
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1140px;
        min-width: 960px;
        z-index: 10;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;

}



.section {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 960px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}


.inner {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding:30px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding:30px 0;
}


/* This is the selector i used for my menu, it needs to be set as position:absolute; */
.subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 462px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 960px;
    background: #aabd46;

}

.subMenu .inner {
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 400;
}





.subNavBtn {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 12%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 2% 0 2%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.end {
    margin: 0;
}


/* SECTIONS */
.sTop {
    min-height: 630px;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    color:#3d3d3d;

}



.s1 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #2e2e2e;
}


.s2 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
}


.s3 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #504f4f;
}


.s4 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #6e87a1;
    color: white;
}

.s5 {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: #293b4d;
    color: white;
}
```

---

### JavaScript

:

```
  (function(){


        $.fn.smint = function( options ) {

            // adding a class to users div
            $(this).addClass('smint')

            var settings = $.extend({
                'scrollSpeed '  : 500
                }, options);


            return $('.smint a').each( function() {


                if ( settings.scrollSpeed ) {

                    var scrollSpeed = settings.scrollSpeed

                }


                ///////////////////////////////////

                // get initial top offset for the menu 
                var stickyTop = $('.smint').offset().top;   

                // check position and make sticky if needed
                var stickyMenu = function(){

                    // current distance top
                    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

                    // if we scroll more than the navigation, change its position to fixed and add class 'fxd', otherwise change it back to absolute and remove the class
                    if (scrollTop > stickyTop) { 
                        $('.smint').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0 }).addClass('fxd');

                        } else {
                            $('.smint').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':stickyTop }).removeClass('fxd'); 
                        }   
                };

                // run function
                stickyMenu();

                // run function every time you scroll
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                     stickyMenu();
                });

                ///////////////////////////////////////


                $(this).on('click', function(e){


                    // gets the height of the users div. This is used for off-setting the scroll so th emenu doesnt overlap any content in the div they jst scrolled to
                    var selectorHeight = $('.smint').height();   

                    // stops empty hrefs making the page jump when clicked
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // get id pf the button you just clicked
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');

                    // gets the distance from top of the div class that matches your button id minus the height of the nav menu. This means the nav wont initially overlap the content.
                    var goTo =  $('div.'+ id).offset().top -selectorHeight;

                    // Scroll the page to the desired position!
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

                }); 



            });

        }

    })();
```

---

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SMINT Demo</title>

<meta name = "keywords" content = "" />
<meta name = "description" content = "" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.smint.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.subMenu').smint({
        'scrollSpeed' : 1000
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrap">

      <div class="subMenu" >
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a> 
            <a href="#" id="s1" class="subNavBtn">About me </a>
            <a href="#" id="s2" class="subNavBtn"> Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Working</a>
            <a href="#" id="s4" class="subNavBtn">Hello</a>
            <a href="#" id="s5" class="subNavBtn end">lets go</a>
        </div>



    </div>


    <div class="section sTop">



        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Welcome to my site </h1>
            <p>Click the links below !</p>

        </div>
        <br class="clear">
    </div>





    <div class="section s1">

        <div class="inner">

            <h1>About me </h1>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section s2">
        <div class="inner">

            <h1>Portfolio</h1>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section s3">
        <div class="inner">

        <h1>Working Standards</h1>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section s4">
        <div class="inner">

            <h1>Hello</h1>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section s5">
        <div class="inner">

        <h1>Lets Go</h1>

        </div>

    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

i think that use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) can help you.

Look at [Navbar in bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) and search for "Fixed to top"

Edit:
If you want something like you post, combine with something like this [Leave menu bar fixed on top when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled) .

When the menu has top offset equals something add class ".navbar-fixed-top".

Answer (score 2):

I tried many times for the solution @Kortschot provided, while finally it turned out to be that this solution wasn't ideal for my situation.

Here is my problem when using the solution @Kortschot provided :

- The **width of floating bar** can not maintain when floating bar's states change between fix or not fix
- I want **all the process can be done in just one script**, while the solution @Kortschot provided doesn't fit.

**Here is my solution which can do all the work in just one script** (using 1.7+ jquery):

```
<script>
//浮动条设置(set the floating bar)
$( function(){
    //add new .fixed style to the <head>
    var css = '#floating_bar.fixed{position:fixed;top:1px;z-index:9999;}',
        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet){ style.styleSheet.cssText = css; } 
    else { style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css)); }
    head.appendChild(style);

    var menuOffset = $("#floating_bar")[0].offsetTop;
    var menuWidth = document.getElementById("floating_bar").offsetWidth;
    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
        var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(docScroll >= menuOffset) { 
            $("#floating_bar").addClass("fixed");
            //dynamically change the width of floating bar according to it's width of previous state 
            $("#floating_bar.fixed").width(menuWidth);
        }else {
            $("#floating_bar").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the URL that you provide, I see a menu bar fixed on the top of browser while you scroll down several lines of the page.

So I separate your problem to 2 questions:
First, how to make a fixed top menu which won't be disappear when scroll the page.
Second, how to make a menu fixed on top after scrolling down few lines.

For the first question, I change your css code.

```
#menucontainer {
    float:top;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: eeee00; /* makes other content won't be seen when the page scrolling */
}
```

And I think the second question need to write js. Well I don't know yet.