# scrollToFixed jquery creating blank div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this plugin works great, but when I stop the scroll fixed position, it creates the following div.

```
<div style="display: block; width: 1621px; height: 104px; float: none;"></div>
```

The dimensions resemble to size of the div being scrolled.

Example: http://litl.it/ simply scroll past the maps area, then scroll back up and there will be an odd blank space.

Anyone know how to remove this issue? I've found one other example that has been closed, but the issue was resolved with a work around creating extra containers, with additional css to comply with the 'random' div created. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

code:

```
<section id="devices" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
    <h1>litl.it now, bookmark it for later</h1>
    <p>we provides an easy link shortening solution with better features above the competition, you can now shorten &amp; bookmark your links with control. 
</section>
<section id="demographic" data-speed="7" data-type="background">
</section>
<div id="mapoverlay">
    <div class="mapcontainer">
        <h1>litl.it it records data of your audience</h1>
        <p>here you can see litl.it users litling links across the world!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="trackstats" data-speed="4" data-type="background">
    <h1>Tracking Stats</h1>
</section>
```

This issue occurs in the Windows Chrome browser (based upon additional comments from users), here is an example:

Edit: it occurs for me in all browsers, maybe the issue is due to the window being too large, resulting in the bottom of the page preventing the scroll from passing over the target div.

Can I please ask you to attempt creating the issue with a small window to ensure the scrolling div passes over the tracking stats box.

[image]

Comment: I'm using FF 30 and I can't recreate the problem.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Maybe this is specific chrome issue or webkit browser issue, I'll add an addition image to demonstrate the issue right now.

Comment: Chrome 35 on OS X and I can recreate the problem either

Comment: @djthoms I'm currently using windows 8 chrome, I'm not sure if this could be a specific Win issue.  I have provided an image example, to help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @samayres1992, even on my VM I'm not seeing the issue using Chrome 35 w/ Win8. You can probably write a little js to remove the div. Perhaps something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/jZ57Z/](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ57Z/)

Comment: Hi @djthoms, thanks for going to effort of double checking, I appreciate it.  I added additional information in the above post, with extra info on recreating the issue.  I have recreated now on ie latest, ff latest, chrome latest. Here is the ff example, http://cl.ly/image/2a1X0c2P3X2B/Image%202014-07-15%20at%204.53.49%20PM.png of the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165915/how-to-build-floating-menu-bar-when-scroll-down take a look at this

Comment: @Bik I gave this a try and the same issue sadly still occured.

Comment: I cannot reproduce in latest Chrome or Firefox. Have you ever tried the ScrollTo plugin? It is the only one I've found to be (so far) glitch free, even on mobile. http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/