# applying transition fade in fade out to sticky nav in css jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, navbar

I have a sticky nav bar appearing at the top of my page when the user scrolls down the page, at the moment it just suddenly pops/appears onto the page. Using the following code from [How to build floating menu bar when scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165915/how-to-build-floating-menu-bar-when-scroll-down)

```
//jQuery Code
//Sticky Nav
var top = jQuery(‘#mydiv’).offset().top - parseFloat(jQuery(‘#mydiv’).css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 100));
jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
// what the y position of the scroll is
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

// whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
  // if so, ad the fixed class
  jQuery(‘#mydiv’).addClass('fixed');


} else {
  // otherwise remove it
  jQuery(‘#mydiv’).removeClass('fixed');
}
});


//CSS
#mydiv.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 3%;
background:#FFFFFF;
font-size: 85% !important;  
}
```

I’d like to add a transition effect to it to fade it in when it appears and fade it out when the menu disappears.

I tried updating the main line jQuery code to

```
//whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
// if so, ad the fixed class
//jQuery(‘#mydiv’).addClass('fixed');

jQuery(‘#mydiv’).css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px', 'opacity':'0', 'left':'0', 'z-index':'1', 'width':'100%', 'border-bottom':'1px solid #000', 'padding':'10px 0px 0px 3%', 'background':'#FFFFFF'}).animate({opacity:1},300);
```

and while it does transition/fades in when the nav appears, the menu glitches / blinks whenever there is scrolling.

If someone could please show me how to do this correctly, any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your code with the classes (it's a lot cleaner) and simply use jQuery's [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) function instead of animating the opacity.

```
if (y >= top) {
  // if so, add the fixed class
  jQuery('#mydiv').addClass('fixed').fadeIn();

} else {
  // otherwise remove it
  jQuery('#mydiv').removeClass('fixed').fadeOut();
}
```

---

Another nice way is to have the bar animate smoothly from the top. You can do this fully in CSS:

```
#mydiv{
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px; //height of the div
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 3%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 85% !important;  
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
    transition: top 0.5s;
}

#mydiv.fixed {
    top: 0;
}
```

You won't need the `fadeIn()` function if you are using the CSS solution.

Comment: hi @Dark Ashelin thanks for the reply, when I do 
    // if so, add the fixed class
      jQuery('#mydiv').addClass('fixed').fadeIn();
      } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      jQuery('#mydiv').removeClass('fixed').fadeOut();

My nav bar disappears at page load and then fades in when I scroll down and disappears when I scroll to the top.

Should I have 2 nav bars, one off screen hidden and then fade that one in when I scroll down??? Is there another way to do it without having 2 identical nav bars/duplicating them?

Comment: If you want it to be smooth, the best way is to have 2 nav bars yes. You can't animate the `position` property.

Comment: ok @Dark Ashelin thanks for the help working beautifully now with fade in fade on 2 menus, I don't need to removeClass no longer, as soon as I took that out it works seamlessly, thanks again for the help!