# Menu bar won't move left or right with scrollbar

Tags: css, menu, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a menu for my website. I've been testing it for smaller screens (for screens around 800 by 600), and everytime I try moving my horizontal scrollbar over to the right to see the whole menu, the body of my website changes but not the menu. Can anyone help? Thanks!
Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/

CSS:

```
div#header-container {
     background-color: #003264; 
     height: 100px !important;
     box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #666;
     min-width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
 }
 div#header {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    /*position: relative;*/
    top: 0;
 }
div#header ul{
    height: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
}
div#header ul li {
    background-color: #003264;  
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    transition: background-color 1s;
     -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    display: inline;
     padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="header-container">
        <div id="header" class="row">   
            <nav class="nav-bar">
                <ul class="left">
                    <li data-slide="1" class="andrewgu"><a href="">andrewgu</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="right">
                    <li data-slide="2" class="portfolio"><a href="">portfolio</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="3" class="about"><a href="">about</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="4" class="contact"><a href="">contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </nav>
        </div><!--end header-->
    </div><!--end header-container-->
```

Edit: Is there a way I can do this in CSS by just having the gap between the left and right menu items decrease as the browser width decreases?

Comment: try to remove `position: fixed` from `div#header-container`, or change `position: fixed` to `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is due to the `position: fixed;` in the css for your menu. It is the expected behavior of a fixed position where it essentially ignores scroll bars. If you want to keep your menu at the top without using the css property I would suggest you look at a javascript solution.

Maybe have a look at this post: [Leave menu bar fixed on top when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled)

Alternatively there is a great jquery plugin that can achieve this as well called jquery-scrollspy which can be found here: https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Foundation.css
A max-width is set. To make it more responive we will use @meta scaling. The If of CSS3.

Use this code:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
  div#header {
    max-width:100%
  }
}
```

If it doesn't work use this in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Add me on skype: JonasRothmann

Check this source code: http://script9.net/basel/

Jonas Rothmann Hjalager

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have it scroll horizontally, but not vertically, you won't come across a CSS only solution. Here is a jQuery solution that should work for you

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('div#header-container').css('left','-'+$(window).scrollLeft()+'px');
});
```