# "Animation" in a navigation bar with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navigationbar

Below is my code and I'm trying to recreate this effect: (http://hideo-html5-css3-bootstrap-website-template.little-neko.com/files/index.html) [When you scroll down the navigaiton bar changes to half size and with some transparency or something like that.] Any ideas to remake it?

Code: http://pastebin.com/r0pS4AYD

Ps: My code has nothing special and I just want a point/direction to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user scolls to an specific position,
 or in your case when he begins to scroll, you can add an class via jQuery.

Look here for more information:

[Leave menu bar fixed on top when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled)

(Code is taken from the post in the link)

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
     }
     else {
         $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
     }
});
```

it is the best when you create an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code, so other people can easy modify your code and see whats going on there..