# how to add bottom fixed nav menu in bootstrap

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed, nav

**Hi there i want to add a fixed bottom menu like this** [demo](http://codeventus.com/themes/genesis/dark/)
 how can i make like this menu with bootstrap ? please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap class `navbar-fixed-bottom` instead of navbar-fixed-top.

For the animation, you have to write some custom code. I would make the navbar to appear with a css transition. This can be done by adding a class to the navbar on a specific scroll position:
["Animation" in a navigation bar with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558960/animation-in-a-navigation-bar-with-bootstrap-3)

Try it on this site: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/