# Keep thead visible on top while scrolling the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

While scrolling I want to keep thead of my table fixed (visible).
I have spent good amount of time searching for a proper solution and found a lot of jquery plugins but none is working fine .

I have the logic but I am not very good with javascript and jquery.
My logic is

I will get the location of my thead and location of scrolltop.
Now as we move the scroll-bar I will move the thead with it(by the same distance) so that it remains always in the top.

Please help me to put it in the form of code. It would be a big help. Or any suggestion to start with is also appreciated.

Comment: did you look at jquery datatables? http://datatables.net/ I use it and it provides the functionality you are requesting.

Comment: Try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled there is a working fiddle that you can reference

Comment: Ya i have tried datatable plugin on my table. It worked but not in the way expected. It keeps the thead in another table tag and adjust the column widths accordingly. Also I found it hard to customize.

Comment: Can any one with knowledge on JS and jquery help me with the idea i have. I have spent lot of time just trying out these plugins already.

Answer (score 1):

With just CSS, you can just set the following properties for the `tbody`

```
tbody {
    height:300px;   /*set a height*/
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/F4C9m/)

*Note: This is assuming that when you said `"while scrolling"`, you meant, scrolling the table, and not the document.*

---

If what you actually meant was make the header "sticky", then you can add this jQuery code:

```
var $thead = $('thead');
var stickyThead = $thead.offset().top;
var theadWidth = $thead.width();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyThead) {
        $thead.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0px',
            width: theadWidth
        });
    } else {
        $thead.css({
            position: 'static',
            top: '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/DqBFP/)

Comment: ya scrolling inside div container that has the table. Can you please elaborate your idea. What about the thead ?

Comment: Check out the [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/F4C9m/) link for the full code. There is no need for a `div` container, and the `thead` is left as is.

Comment: will the column headers allign with the column values

Comment: because in my case i must have adjustable column headers. YOu must be able to resize in runtime