# I want to turn my menu fixed on top

Tags: javascript, scroll, menu, navbar, fixed

My menu is hidden/show, but I want to keep it on the top of the page when I scroll.

The HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="#home"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
        <a href="#servicces"><li>Services</li></a>
        <a href="#projects"><li>Work</li></a>
        <a href="#contact"><li>Contact</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu-toggle">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.menu {
  display:none;
    width:100%;
  background:#fcfcfc;
}
.menu ul {
    font-family: 'Raleway', serif;
  font-weight:300;
  height:110%;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.menu ul li {
    color:#333;
    font-size:12px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    padding:15px 0;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  text-align:center;
    background:rgba(90,221,184,.6);
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration:none;
    color: #333;
}
.menu-toggle {
    background:none;
  color: #333;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0;
    font-size:25px;
}
.menu-toggle a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #333;
}
.fa-angle-double-down{
  color:#fcfcfc;
  transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.fa-angle-double-down:hover{
  color:#5ADDB8;
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-toggle a").click(function(){ 
        $(".menu").slideToggle(700);
    });
});
```

I'd like to get the arrow on top, and when it is clicked, it moves down and gets the menu on the top, after closing the menu, the arrow back to its initial place.

Visit the menu codepen: [HERE](http://codepen.io/giuliachristie/pen/wazbyv)

Visit my page trying: [HERE](http://codepen.io/giuliachristie/pen/doPYmw)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Leave menu bar fixed on top when scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274592/leave-menu-bar-fixed-on-top-when-scrolled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in the menu css:

```
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
```

And add the following in your arrow css:

```
    position:relative;
```

That should do what you are thinking to do.

**Edit:**

```
.menu-container{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}
.menu{
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.menu-toggle{
   margin:0 auto;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: The fixed position worked, but the relative (the arrow) didn't. It stays on the same place, but not on the bottom of the menu. You can see [here](http://codepen.io/giuliachristie/full/wazbyv/)

Comment: Looks like you only changed the menu css and not arrow css.  I do not see the `position:relative` property added in arrow's css (`fa-angle-double-down`).  Also, remove `margin-top:0;`.  Edited my script accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, i changed the Menu-Toggle css, but i fixed like you said and the error continues...

Comment: Ok. I see your point.  In this case, you have to wrap both into a menu container and assign the fixed class to the container.  See Edit section in the answer.

Comment: OMG! You did it! Thank you so much! Now works so beautifuly <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div class="menu navbar-fixed-top"></div>
```

Comment: But how can i turn this new class fixed?

Comment: It's a bootstrap class that fixes that div to the top.