# Stop propagation not working as intended. Jquery

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I have some jquery code that hides a div when scroll position does not equal 0. This works well however whenever I scroll up and down at the top of the page very fast, or use a go to top of page link, the events seem to bubble up, making the div appear and reappear a few times... is there a way to make it either appear or disappear and never stack the events in order?

I tried stoppropogation() and this did not seem to work. Maybe I was implementing it incorrectly.

```
    $(window).scroll(
        {
            previousTop: 0
        }, 
        function () {
        var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentTop == 0) {
            $("#binding-info").fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $("#binding-info").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        this.previousTop = currentTop;
    });
```

Comment: How u tried please repeat it

Comment: I just put event.stopPropagation(); between all of the pieces of code, in different combinations. None seemed to work.

Comment: That's because `scroll` event is fired many times. Consider throttling the handler.

Comment: @BlackSheep what do you mean by throttling the handler? How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll event firing too many times. I only want it to fire a maximum of, say, once per second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because jQuery queue animations and `fadeIn/fadeOut` are animations. Basically, jQuery register what animation should be next and do it when the current animation is done.

To stop that, you can use `.stop()` before animating the object.

```
if (currentTop == 0) {
    $("#binding-info").stop().fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    $("#binding-info").stop().fadeOut('slow');
}
```

But there is a problem with `fadeIn`. If you do the `fadeOut` before it reach 1 opacity, it will keep it in data and will not `fadeIn` to 1 again.

The hot fix would be to use `fadeTo()`:

```
$("#binding-info").stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly and without adding another .js file :) thank you!