# jQuery: How can I improve this scrolling event that is being fired too many times?

Tags: jquery, scroll

This code works and does the job, but its EXTREMMELY poor + rudimentary and have some issues with scrolling event. Can somebody help me to optimize the scrolling event?

Prototype: http://codepen.io/rootion/pen/gpZZpG

**Structure and desired behaviour:**

- There are two containers, `.layout__left` (red) and `.layout__right` (green).
- The green container will have the main content and will scroll normally.
- The red container will have the navigation so it will have less content and should scroll up to a certain point only, until the menu reaches the border of the page.

**This is what I am doing:**

1. First both containers scroll normally.
2. When scrolling down the red container, if the scroll position + window size is bigger than the li:last child position (couldnt think of anyway to detect the "bottom"), then the container has a position fixed.
3. When scrolling up, the fixed position is disabled and when the menu reaches the top of the document, the position is fixed again, and then removed.

As I said, this does the job. But it's slow and has glitches while scrolling. I think its because I am doing on the scroll event and its being executed in every pixel.

I tried throttling the function call, but the code doesn't function at all:

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $.throttle(100, sectionScroll));
    });

    sectionScroll = function() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    var left = $('.layout__left');
    var right = $('.layout__right');
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var viewport = $(window).height();
    var lastChild = $('.navigation > ul > li:last-child').offset().top;

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - scroll) <= delta)
    return;

    if (scroll > lastScrollTop){
    // SCROLL DOWN
    left.removeClass('top absolute');

    // if the last item of the left is visible
    if (  (scroll + viewport) > (lastChild + 30)  ) {
    // make the left fixed
    left.addClass('fixed bottom');
    console.log("bottom!");
    }

    // SCROLL UP
    } else {
    // remove fixed class from left
    left.removeClass('fixed bottom');
    left.addClass('absolute bottom');

    if ( scroll <= left.position().top   ) {
    left.removeClass('bottom absolute');
    left.addClass('top fixed');
    left.removeClass('top fixed');
    console.log("top!");
    }
    }

    lastScrollTop = scroll;
    };
```

Any feedback?

Comment: your codepen code doesn't match the code in this post.

Comment: At least in the code you're posting, you're running $.throttle(100, sectionScroll)); every time there is even a single pixel change in xy coords. That's going to run a LOT, and it might even repeat.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617517/1090538

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to put this somewhere in your script:

```
var isStarted = false;
```

Then, in your start function:

```
if(!isStarted) {
    isStarted = true;
//other stuff
} else {
    return false; //because it's already doing it's thing
}
```

In your stop function:

```
isStarted = false;
```