# Remove Fixed Position in JavaScript after Scrolling Some Distance

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I have an  set its position to fixed on top of the page. This will make this  follows me while scrolling down to the middle of the document or page. After the middle of document, I want to stick this  in middle of document, and scoll down without it. After I scroll up again, I want it back to follow me (fixed position).

Here is a snippet of code I am working on.

```
            if ($('body').hasClass('catalog-product-view')) {

                if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.product-collateral-wrapper').innerHeight()/2)
                {
                    my div should remain in its place now. waiting for me to scoll up again to follow me
                }else{
have my div fixed positioned so when I scroll the page, I always see it. 
}

Here is the full function
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset && !stickyActive) { 
                stickyActive = true;
                $header.addClass("sticky-active");
                $(stickyPlaceholder).show();
                var logo = $('<li></li>').append($('.main-header .logo-container > a').clone()).html();
                logo = '<li class="logo-fixed">'+logo+'</li>';
                $('.main-header nav.top-bar.main-nav .top-bar-section .left').prepend(logo);
                if ($('.top-bar-section .main-logo-sticky').length) {
                    $('.top-bar-section .main-logo').hide();
                }
                topbarLeftHeight = $('.main-header nav.top-bar.main-nav .top-bar-section .left').outerHeight();
            } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < offset && stickyActive) {
                $header.removeClass("sticky-active");
                $('nav.top-bar.main-nav .logo-fixed').remove();
                $(stickyPlaceholder).hide();
                stickyActive = false;
            }
            if ($('body').hasClass('catalog-product-view') && Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 64.063em)')) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.magellan-nav.magellan-fixed').css('margin-top',topbarLeftHeight+'px');
                },100);
            }



//HERE GOES CHANGES I AM DOING. It started to make sense how to get it working, but will this be effecient or will it have performance drawback cause of scroll event is triggered with every scroll, and same calculations will be redone again and again?

            if ($('body').hasClass('catalog-product-view')) {



                if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.product-collateral-wrapper').innerHeight()/2)
                    {
//will enter code here`l toggle position and top property here based on some calculations
                    }else{
   //will toggle position and top property here based on some calculations
    }
                }





            });
            $(window).scroll();
        };
```

I tried changing position from fixed to relative. This will take  back to top of page making it invisible within viewport.

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: do you want this to occur with an image?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the element to follow you down to a point, almost as if it hits an invisible wall further down in the page? In this case I would recommend determining that break point (in pixels from the top of the page) and set its position to `absolute` with the `top` value you've calculated. Toggle the positioning logic onScroll and onResize, and also probably throttle the callback while you're at it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Lincoln Anderson.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but without the code it is hard to provide a solid answer.

My best stab at it is to first get the page working with the `div` you mentioned placed at the center of the page how you want it to appear after scrolling halfway. Once you have that, create a secondary css setup using an additional class so that it is fixed to the top of the page:

```
.div-class {
  // standard css here
}
.div-class.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Once you are happy with the two versions, then work on your jquery script to toggle the additional class on/off based on the window position: that you can search for easily enough and find a good solution. As Lincoln mentioned, you may want to throttle the script so that it doesn't run every time the scroll event happens.

Comment: Great. If I may ask, what do you mean by " throttle the script so that it doesn't run every time the scroll event happens"? I am not from JS background, but it sound the method I have will cause performance issues as the event is triggered on scrolling!. I will modify my question to add more code now.

Comment: Check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on

Comment: Added the whole function there. I have not yet included the part of setting top and toggling classes for fixed position as it is now clear and will do it. The question now will such method cause performance issues as it is called with every scroll in that page?

Comment: Did you add the function from the question or the accepted answer? That is the key to resolving the performance issues. http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with an image you can set the `background-image`, `background-size` (if you want to change the size of the image), `background-repeat`, and `background-attachment` properties within a `div`.

**background-image**
set the `background-image` to the url or location in which your image is located within your folder.

**background-repeat**
set the `background-repeat` to `no-repeat` so the `background-image` will not repeat throughout your `div`

**background-attachment**
set the `background-attachment` to `fixed`. It will stay in position until the `div` is scrolled to the end.

Since you want the image to disappear once you've hit the middle of the page set your `div`s `height` to `50%` and set your `html` and `body` height to `100%`

**Example:**

```css
html, body {
  height: 3000px;
}

#coolCat {
  background-image: url("https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/cool-wallpaper-1.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id='coolCat'></div>
```