# Keep place in content when resizing the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to stop the content from scrolling when a window's size is changed?

I am working on a responsive website with long form content. When the browser window is resized the reader's place in the content in shifted. This makes for a poor user experience as they have to find their place in the content again.

A good example of this is the bootstrap doc site. Try resizing your window near the bottom of the docset and you will be look at something completely different after resizing. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Mozilla bug from 1999 dealing with an issue I'm facing #retrobug
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19261

Answer (score 2):

[Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is your friend here. You can possibly figure out which element is at the top of the window at your brake-points (using the [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize)) off course, and call `element.scrollIntoView()` on that element.

You can detect which element is closest to the top using a function like:

```
function closestToTop() {
  const top = window.scrollY;
  return [].reduce.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3'),
    (closest, el) => Math.abs(offsetTop(el) - top) <= Math.abs(offsetTop(closest) - top)
      ? el
      : closest,
    document.body
  );
}
```

where you get `offsetTop` with:

```
function offsetTop(el, offset = 0) {
  if (el === document.body) {
    return 0;
  }

  return offset + el.offsetTop + offsetTop(el.offsetParent);
}
```

We  limit our self to `<h1>`, `<h2>`, and `<h3>` elements to make the computation a little easier.

What you want to do is figuring out what element is at the top at a beginning of resize and scroll to it only if it is off screen at the end of scroll. So we need to apply some sort of [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on):

```
{
  let throttling = false;

  function throttledResize() {
    if (throttling) {
      return;
    }

    throttling = true;
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('resizeStart'));
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('resizeEnd'));
      throttling = false;
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener('resize', throttledResize);
}
```

Now we have the `'resizeStart'` and `'resizeEnd'` events. Note, we put this in ECMAScript2015 block scope so we are not polluting the global scope with the `throttling` and `throttleResize` variables. Now we can close over whatever element was at the top when resize started (again using block scope).

```
{
  let wasAtTop = null;

  window.addEventListener('resizeEnd', () => {
    if (!wasAtTop) {
      return;
    }

    wasAtTop.scrollIntoView();
    wasAtTop = null;
  });

  window.addEventListener('resizeStart', () => {
    wasAtTop = closestToTop();
  });
}
```

Note: This is highly un-optimized. There are various improvements that we can add to this. Like throttle for longer time than until next animation frame, and never scroll unless the element is actually outside of the view `window.scrollY < offsetTop(el) && offsetTop(el) < window.scrollY + window.height`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm wondering. How would I "figure out which element is at the top of the window"?

Comment: I edited the answer with a further attempt to achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to keep the top at pixel-level exactly where before the window is resized (e.g. in the middle of a div). But as a workaround, you can use some divs (e.g. section titles) as "anchors": whenever user scrolls, detect and keep track of what anchor div is currently in view, and pin the page back to the anchor after the resize.

More specifically, take the link you provided as an example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Let's say you want all the `<h1>` tags as anchors (you can use h2 instead, or h1+h2, depending on how detailed control you want): 
`var anchorDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");`

and as a place to start (without testing every corner scenario), I put together this function to detect the first anchor div currently in view:

```
function getAnchorDiv(anchorDivs) {
    var viewTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop; // IE
    var viewBottom = viewTop + window.innerHeight;
    var anchorDiv;
    for (var i = 0; i < anchorDivs.length; i++) {
        var anchorDiv = anchorDivs[i];
        // gets the cumulative offset top of current div
        var anchorDivTop = anchorDiv.offsetTop;
        var tempDiv = anchorDiv.offsetParent;
        while (tempDiv) {
            anchorDivTop += tempDiv.offsetTop
            tempDiv= tempDiv.offsetParent;
        }
        if (anchorDivTop >= viewTop && anchorDivTop < viewBottom) {
            // this div is the first one in view
            break;
        } else if (anchorDivTop >= viewBottom) {
            // page view doesn't contain any anchor div, so give the one that's just scrolled over (previous anchor div in the array)
            anchorDiv = anchorDivs[(i-1) >= 0 ? (i-1) : 0];
            break;
        }
    }
    return anchorDiv;
}
```

When user scrolls, update the anchor div:

```
var anchorDiv = anchorDivs[0];
document.onscroll = function() { 
    anchorDiv = getAnchorDiv(anchorDivs); 
}
```

And finally on resize, scroll to that anchor div like @Rúnar Berg suggested:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    anchorDiv.scrollIntoView();
};
```

---

If just to stay at hash locations in the url, you can reset the window.location.href after resize:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    window.location.href = "http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels";
};
```

Comment: ty @js. That works when there's only anchor you want to keep people at. What about if you're at a different point in the page? I guess you would have to keep a record of where in the page you are and reference that point. Is there a way to keep track of where you are in the page (what id you're at)?

Comment: @IanEdington I see your point now. Just updated my answer and I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: This looks great. I'll try it out this weekend and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the content in our window during resizing, we first need to know how far down the page we've scrolled via a percentage.

```
var percent;
window.addEventListener("scroll", getScrollPercent);
function getScrollPercent() {
    percent = window.pageYOffset / document.body.scrollHeight;
}
```

First, I've made `percent` a global variable because we'll use that value in another function momentarily.

Second, this function not is giving us the percentage of the page scrolled, but rather the percent from the top of the body to the top of the window (you'll never get 100%). This works to our advantage though because our next function is going to call `window.scrollTo()` which scrolls a certain amount based on the offset from the top of the page.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    var Ypos = document.body.scrollHeight * percent;
    window.scrollTo(0, Ypos);
});
```

We use our previously calculated "percentage" to determine where the scrollbar should be now that the page has resized, and then we plug said value into `window.scrollTo()` for Y, leaving our X value as 0.

Hopefully this works for everyone, and I apologize in advance if my phrasing is confusing/off.