# Show/Hide Sub-Header based on Scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Question:** I am trying to accomplish the following animation: When the page loads in mobile I want to show the div with the ID "sub-header" but as soon as the user scrolls more than 50px down the page I want to .hide sub-header.  Finally if the user scrolls up 60px anytime while on the page I want sub-header to .show

**What I am seeing with the code below:** The page hides the menu but when I scroll up it shows and hides multiple times after I stop scrolling.

JQuery:

```
 var newScroll = 0;

 var subHeaderPosition = true;

 var currentScroll = 0;

         $(window).scroll(function () {

             currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

               if ($(window).width() < 779) {

                       if (currentScroll > 50 && subHeaderPosition) {

                           console.log("Current Scroll position: " + currentScroll);

                            console.log("Scroll should hide");

                            $("#sub-header").hide(300);

                            subHeaderPosition = false;

                            newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                            console.log("New Scroll position: " + newScroll);

                       } else if ((currentScroll - 60) < newScroll && !subHeaderPosition) {

                           console.log("Scroll position: " + currentScroll);

                            console.log("Scroll should show Sub-Header");

                            $("#sub-header").show(300);

                            subHeaderPosition = true;

                            newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                       } else {

                           newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                       }




               }

          });
```

**UPDATE:** After adding a few more logs I can now tell that my newscroll and currentscroll are always ending up the same number which points me in the right direction. I will post a solution once I have it or if anyone figures it out I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for fixing issue

```
$(function(){

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 50){
    $('header').addClass('hide');
}
else if($(window).scrollTop() <= 60){
    $('header').removeClass('hide');
}

});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qummetov_/3hf1e350/

Comment: Unfortunately I want the "header to show if the user starts the scroll up not just when they get to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with hide/show time arguments. Because of it, while the hide action could done, the scroll actually asynchronously doing.

Checkout [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nicat13/gqq6dgz7/5/).

I'm checking this correctivity with the `canShowHeader` variable.
In my case I'm running a fake setTimeout, but you can use original [jquery hide/show case](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete):

Example:

```
$( "#book" ).show(300, function() {
  canShowHeader = false;
});
```

and

```
$( "#book" ).hide(300, function() {
  canShowHeader = true;
});
```

Hope It helps...

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of using addClass and removeClass, as @Ниязи Гумметов has said, because you can only remove and add a class once.

Something like this:

```js
var newScroll = 0;

var subHeaderPosition = true;

var currentScroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();


  if (currentScroll > 50 && subHeaderPosition) {

    console.log("Current Scroll position: " + currentScroll);

    console.log("Scroll should hide");

    $("#sub-header").removeClass("show");
    $("#sub-header").addClass("hide");

    subHeaderPosition = false;

    newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    console.log("New Scroll position: " + newScroll);

  } else if ((currentScroll - 60) < newScroll && !subHeaderPosition) {

    console.log("Scroll position: " + currentScroll);

    console.log("Scroll should show Sub-Header");

    $("#sub-header").addClass("show");


    subHeaderPosition = true;

    newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  } else {

    newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  }


});
```

```css
#sub-header {
  margin-top: 500px;
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Or just extract [Underscore Throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) as [nicholaides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/) mentioned.