# Scrolltop fires scroll event multiple times; how to restrict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to make a navbar that changes if you're not at the top of the page. Here is the JavaScript in question:

```
$('.myLinks a').click( function() {
    let idLink = $(this).text().toLowerCase()
     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(`#${idLink}`).offset().top-80
     }, 800);
});

$(window).scroll(() => {
    let value = $(this).scrollTop()
    if (value > 80) {
        $('.myNav').css({'opacity':'1', 'height':'60px'})
    }
    else $('.myNav').css({'opacity':'0.5', 'height':'80px'})
})
```

The first function is for smooth-scrolling to the div associated with the link. However, when I click one of these links, the scroll value resets to 0 (causing the navbar to reset to how it appears at the top of the page), then the navbar changes back to how it should. The navbar changes for only a split-second, but it's still noticeable.

How do I fix this? I can provide more details as needed.

SOLVED: As suggested by @MichaelCoker below, it turned out my links were redirecting to "#" before scrolling to where it should, causing the jump to position 0.

Comment: Set up a jsFiddle Patrick. It looks like you are using es2015 JavaScript and jQuery and you're syntax is missing `;`s and has wild indents. - It's best to make a small example. : )

Comment: I'm assuming you need to change `$('.myLinks a').click( function()` to `$('.myLinks a').click( function(e)` and add `e.preventDefault();` in the click handler. Sounds like you're navigating to `#` when you click on the link. Setting up a demo with your actual code would help.

Comment: @sheriffderek This is a small example. Don't create a fiddle, you can use the code tool inside here. In any case, this has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on

Comment: @JuanMendes I wouldn't have suggested it if the OP wasn't new. ; )

Comment: Thank you all for the help; I definitely should've posted a demo, and I will next time I ask a question. At any rate, @MichaelCoker was correct in that I was linking back to `#` before scrolling to my intended target. Thanks all!