# $(window).scroll(function() loads many times

Tags: javascript, ajax, scroll

I'm working with scroll function, the problem is that it loads many times and  it doesn't wait for the new information plased by the db.

Here's the code!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
    
     if(($('#postList').height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())&& (lastID != 0)){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getData.php',
            data:'id='+lastID,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('.load-more').show();             },
            success:function(html){
                $('.load-more').remove();
                $('#postList').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: You probably need to take a look at the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) if your aim is to load more content as the user scrolls down the page?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll event firing too many times. I only want it to fire a maximum of, say, once per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613594/scroll-event-firing-too-many-times-i-only-want-it-to-fire-a-maximum-of-say-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to prevent an AJAX request to start while another one is running, use a variable to return from the scroll function. Set it to true right before the AJAX request and reset it to false in the `always` handler:

```
var loading = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(loading)
            return;

        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
        
        if(($('#postList').height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())&& (lastID != 0)){
            loading = true;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getData.php',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('.load-more').show();             
                },
                success:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    $('#postList').append(html);
                },
                always: function() {
                    loading = false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

(untested)

As @ProfessorAbronsius suggested in the comments: Take a look at the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) as well. Seems to be a more stable approach.

Comment: wow, it works but just for one time, it should load more times :(

Comment: It's probably your if statement preventing it from loading more times, since the `loading` variable is set back after the request finished. Set a breakpoint and check where it is failing the second time. I cannot test it locally with the information you provided.

Comment: you were right, i had to do it on getData.php  too... thanks! it works now.... :)  <3